# Match and substitute elements using AWK

Tags: regex, awk

I have a straight-forward problem. If element in the first column (ID) of "file" matches with elements of first column (ID) of "subfile", the matched element of "file" should be replaced by element of second column (i.e by Symbol) of "subfile".

I am able to match the "IDs" in "file" and "subfile" using "AWK", but in a trouble of substituting the matched elements with the corresponding "symbols".

Any suggestions please.

The script I have written for matching IDs is:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$1;next} 1' subfile file
```

SUBFILE:

```
"ID"    "Symbol"
"204639_at" "ADA"
"204212_at" "ACOT8"
"209027_at" "ABI1"
"202382_at" "GNPDA1"
```

FILE

```
"ID"        "x"  "y"   "z"
"204639_at" 1.22  2.33  4.66
"204212_at" 3.55  5.78  4.78
"209027_at" 4.77  3.21  9.30
"202382_at" 9.66  9.08  1.43
```

The output I need is as follows:

```
         x      y        z

ADA     1.22    2.33    4.66
ACOT8   3.55    5.78    4.78
ABI1    4.77    3.21    9.3
GNPDA1  9.66    9.08    1.43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} {$1=a[$1]}1' subfile file
"Symbol" "x" "y" "z"
"ADA" 1.22 2.33 4.66
"ACOT8" 3.55 5.78 4.78
"ABI1" 4.77 3.21 9.30
"GNPDA1" 9.66 9.08 1.43
```

Or some formatted:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} {$1=a[$1];gsub(/\"/,"");gsub(/Symbol/,"")}1' OFS="\t" subfile file
        x       y       z
ADA     1.22    2.33    4.66
ACOT8   3.55    5.78    4.78
ABI1    4.77    3.21    9.30
GNPDA1  9.66    9.08    1.43
```

Comment: @Jidder Here you are wrong. It store the `subfile` in an array named `a` using `$1` as index and `$2` as value.  Then when it looks in the `file` it takes the value from `$1` from  `file` and use it in the array `a` as look up. If match is found return it and store it back to `$1` (`$1=a[$1]`)  Just try to swap some of the lines in `subfile` around and you will still get same result.

Comment: Although the reason for my confusion was i thought that you are assigning `$1` `$1=a[$1]` to itself for every line in the first file as i dint see the next.

Comment: Also if the first field is not matched it will not preserve what is there and will print a blank field

Comment: @Jidder Can be fixed easily by testing the array while setting `$1` like this `$1=a[$1]?a[$1]:$1`, but OP did not mention the need for it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `join`:

```
join -j 1 FILE SUBFILE -o 2.2,1.2,1.3,1.4 | \
    sed 's/Symbol//;s/"//g;s/  */:/g' | column -t -s:
```

*Gives:*

```
        x     y     z
ADA     1.22  2.33  4.66
ACOT8   3.55  5.78  4.78
ABI1    4.77  3.21  9.30
GNPDA1  9.66  9.08  1.43
```